# Apply SSL into IONIC Apps or Angular Web

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, ssl, ionic-framework

I am new to this.

I have a app that build with IONIC, the backends(authentication, storage, DB) are running at firebase, and the IONIC will call some 3rd party API or my own API that build with node.js and hosted at heroku.

I would like to implement SSL to achieve point to point encryption, so that the real client data won't being hijack by fraud public wifi.

I have no clue where to start and how to do it, please advise and recommend.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

All access to Firebase's backend services goes through secure connections (HTTPS/SSL). There is no way to access them through a non-secured connection.

To access for example the Firebase Database from your Ionic application, have a look at the [documentation on getting started for web developers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start).

Comment: is that mean, by default, the connection with firebase is already secured with HTTPS/SSL?

Comment: The only way to access Firebase backend services is through a secured connection. So if you have that code accesses Firebase backend services, that will be going through a secure connection.

Comment: other than firebase? like node.js etc, have any idea?